# Differentiation of Summation Series / Matrix Multiplication

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, summation, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I have a question regarding how to evaluate the following expression:

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial x_{i}}\sum_{j=1}^{m} \sum_{k=1}^{m} \frac{1}{2}x_{j}x_{k}\sigma_{jk}$$

Can someone explain the process of working this out. I think all terms where j is not equal to I should disappear but I cannot seem to get the answer. Shown below:

$$\sum_{j=1}^{m} x_{j}\sigma_{ij}$$

I am particular confused as to why the factor of one halve disappears. Any help or pointers would be great.

After working some of this through, I believe that the answer is only true if $\sigma_{jk} = \sigma_{kj}$.

Comment: The $i$ in the sum is known as a dummy variable and has nothing to do with the derivative you are trying to perform ... do the derivative with respect to $x_k$ ...

Comment: write it out explicitly for a small value of $m$ ...$2$ or $3$ ... The answer you state is correct, it just needs a factor of $2$ & the summation variable should be $j$.

Comment: I missed the factor $1/2$  did you put it in your edit? ... Basically you pick up a row & column so you get every term twice, apart from at the intersection where you differentiate the square!

Comment: Can we prove this in a formal way using the summation terms?

Comment: Also is this only true when $\sigma_{ij} = \sigma_{ji}$?

Comment: Yes, that's right ... $\sigma $ needs to be symmetric.

Comment: Thanks - you can prove it more formally by splitting out the summation terms and working it through